# why this code does not show the speed

Tags: c#

I create a program for show me speed of internet. For example I need to show `26.365 KB/S` but it show me this `270000000`.

Code :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int KB = 1024;
    int MB = KB * KB;
    int GB = MB * KB;
    NetworkInterface[] nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

    foreach (NetworkInterface nic in nics)
    {
        if (nic.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback
            && nic.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Tunnel
            && nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up
            && nic.Name.StartsWith("vEthernet") == false
            && nic.Description.Contains("Hyper-v") == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(nic.Description);

            long speed = nic.Speed / KB;
            Console.WriteLine("=====================");
            if (speed < KB)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Byte", speed);
            }
            else
            {
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(speed < 100))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} KB/S", speed);
                }
                else if (Convert.ToBoolean(speed < 1000))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} MB/S", speed);
                }
                else if (Convert.ToBoolean(speed < 10000))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} GB/S", speed);
                }
                else if (Convert.ToBoolean(speed < 100000))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} TB/S", speed);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Its not work. It not show me speed. Whats the problem? How can I solve this problem?

/************************************************************************/

Comment: Why C#7 tag? What new feature have you used?

Comment: just for this you give me Negative point ?

Comment: From the [NetworkInterface docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.speed(v=vs.110).aspx): "The value returned by this property is reported by the network interface. It is not computed dynamically."  To me this indicates that it's telling you the maximum throughput, not the measured speed of some connection.  Also, you can lose the `Convert.ToBoolean` calls.  The values returned by the `<` tests are already boolean values.

Comment: That value is bigger than all of your limits according to the if-statements you have there, in which case it shouldn't display anything. Can you verify what the value of `nic.Speed` is?

Comment: Also, it seems you have some odd limits there, if it is less than `KB`, which is 1024, you display something, but the next two if-statements would also potentially match the value.

Comment: @kianoush: no, i haven't

Comment: "Speed of the Internet" :-D

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm sorry

Comment: I think your values are way off. Which value did you get from your network card and what is the speed rating for that card? I ask because a gigabit network card here on my computer reports 10,000,000,000, which is 10 giga-something. If I divide by 1000 (instead of 1024, since the number is seemingly devoid of 1024-multiplies), I get 10 million, still above your numbers but according to your if-statements this value should now be less than 10 thousand. Can you clarify where you got those numbers from and what they mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like you're missing a few things:

1. According to [the NetworkInterface.Speed Property 
   documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.Speed);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true), the `Speed` property is returning `bits` per second, so before we start comparisons, we should convert that to `bytes` by dividing it by 8 (not by `KB`).
2. When doing the comparisons, we should compare the speed value to our placeholders for `KB`, `MB`, `GB`, and `TB` rather than literal numbers. This will reduce error and make it easier to read. For example, you are comparing the speed with multiples of 10 rather than 1024.
3. Your `if` statements don't catch all conditions, only those less than 100000.
4. We need to divide our speed by the size that we're displaying (you only divided it once, by `KB`, at the beginning)
5. If you want to show decimal places, we should convert the number to a decimal before doing the division, and then format the result to show 3 decimal places.

Here's one way to fix these things:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int KB = 1024;
    int MB = KB * KB;
    int GB = MB * KB;
    long TB = (long)GB * KB;

    NetworkInterface[] nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

    foreach (NetworkInterface nic in nics)
    {
        if (nic.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback
            && nic.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Tunnel
            && nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up
            && nic.Name.StartsWith("vEthernet") == false
            && nic.Description.Contains("Hyper-v") == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(nic.Description);

            // 1. Convert bits to bytes
            // 5. Convert result to decimal
            decimal speed = (decimal)nic.Speed / 8;

            // 2. Do comparisons with our variables and
            // 3. Include all possible conditions (starting with > TB)
            if (speed >= TB)
            {
                // 4. Divide the speed by the display size
                // 5. Format the output to show 3 decimal places
                Console.WriteLine("Speed: {0:0.000} TB/S", speed / TB);
            }
            else if (speed >= GB)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Speed: {0:0.000} GB/S", speed / GB);
            }
            else if (speed >= MB)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Speed: {0:0.000} MB/S", speed / MB);
            }
            else if (speed >= KB)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Speed: {0:0.000} KB/S", speed / KB);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Speed: {0:0.000} Bytes per second", speed);
            }
        }
    }

    Console.Write("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is located into your conditions.

If your speed is greater than 100000, there is no else case in which your code must go.

You should write it like that (removing `if` in the last `else if`):

```
if (speed < KB)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} Byte", speed);
}
else
{
    if (speed < 100)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} KB/S", speed);
    }
    else if (speed < 1000)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} MB/S", speed);
    }
    else if (speed < 10000)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} GB/S", speed);
    }
    else 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} TB/S", speed);
    }
}
```

Also, you do not need to convert the result as in the code above.

Comment: @kianoush `It not show me speed` > in my case your code does not show the speed because none of the condition are hit by my interface speed. `I need to show 26.365 KB/S but it show me this 270000000.` > According to your code, it is impossible that the console output does not show the unit. Are you really executing this code?

Comment: i add `000` in all my conditions . it show me `263671 KB/S`

Comment: @kianoush The download speed is relative to the server you are downloding from. Your code does not provide this value. It is just providing the maximum speed handled by your NIC. But this is not what you ask. You ask why your code does not show the speed, this is why.

Comment: You don't need to add `000`, you just need a simple `else` (instead of `else if`) in the last condition to be sure one of them will be hit. Also, I just focus on why your code does not show the output but it looks like you can simplify a lot your conditions.

Comment: @kianoush `now how can i solve this problem` > this is another problem. You can ask a new question if you want to solve it.

Answer (score -4):

Current Implementation

```
long speed = nic.Speed / KB;
```

Instead you should use datatype that support decimal

```
decimal speed = (decimal)nic.Speed/KB;
```

Comment: Since `nic.Speed` is a long (`Int64`) and `KB` is `int`, this won't do what you want it to do. Nor will it likely change the outcome of the code.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen but my math says if integer is divided by another integer you can get decimal result as well. 3/2 = 1.5  but in computing if I use integer to hold resulting number it will either round up or round down to nearest value so to hold actual value one should use decimal type. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: if you divide long by int you will get long **in C#**, as well as most programming languages (not all mind you). To explicitly get a decimal result containing fractional values, cast at least one of the operands to decimal before dividing.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen what if we cast nic Speed to decimal then

Comment: This will reduce rounding "problems" but I think this is completely orthogonal to his problem. In other words, this would probably display better fractional speeds, once he fixes the **actual** problem with his code.